# web3 estimateGas() from fallback function

Tags: web3js, javascript, gas-estimate, fallback-function

When I sign and send raw transactions with web3 in javascipt , to call a method from Smart Contract, I always pass the transaction gas variable after getting it with estimateGas function, from Smart Contract method, as following:

```
mySmartContract= new web3.eth.Contract(SmartContractABI, SmartContractAddress);
mySmartContract.methods.set(inputnum).estimateGas({from: miAddress})
      .then(function(gas){
          tx.gas = web3.utils.toHex(gas);
        })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log("Set() - catch error");
        console.log(error);
      });
```

How could I do the same to invoke the fallback function from the Smart Contract?
estimateGas() is a function from "methods" object, but "fallback" is not a method.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After some research & testing I found the solution by mysef. As a fallback function is unnamed, I just need to use estimateGas with the "eth" object to get the gas stimation of the default function (fallback):

```
const web3eth = require('web3-eth');
const eth = new web3eth('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/XXXXXXX');
    
var tx = {};
tx.gas;

eth.estimateGas({
      from: miAddress
    })
    .then(function(gas) {
      tx.gas = web3.utils.toHex(gas);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Estimategas() - catch error");
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var estimatedGas = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
  from: "0xa89a9290DD214B9341dc09Fe23eF0a6a633F9a9F",
   to: tokencontract,
   data: tk.methods.updateMinted(id).encodeABI()
 })




var tip = await web3.eth.getMaxPriorityFeePerGas()


var block = await web3.eth.getBlock("pending")

const baseFee = Number(block.baseFeePerGas);
const max = Number(tip) + baseFee; //increse to speed up






const tx = {
  to: tokencontract,
  gas:  web3.utils.toHex(estimatedGas),
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: web3.utils.toHex(Number(tip)),
  maxFeePerGas: web3.utils.toHex(max),
  data: tk.methods.updateMinted(id).encodeABI(),

};

const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey);
```